# Running iterated regressions for data divided into N chunks in R

Tags: r, loops, regression, apply

I have a dataframe structured like the following:

```
birthwt  tobacco01  pscore  pscoreblocks
3425     0          0.18    (0.177, 0.187]
3527     1          0.15    (0.158, 0.168]
1638     1          0.34    (0.335, 0.345]
```

The birthwt column is a continuous variable measuring birth weight in grams. The tobacco01 column contains values of 0 or 1. The pscore column contains probability values between 0 and 1. The pscoreblocks takes the pscore column and breaks it down into 100 equally sized blocks.

I am trying to find an efficient way to do the following for each of the blocks in pscoreblocks. I have included the code that would work if I was running this on the entire dataset without partitioning into blocks.

1- Run the regression.

```
one <- lm(birthwt ~ tobacco01, dfc)
```

2- Take the value of the coefficient on the tobacco01 variable in the regression.

```
two <- summary(one)$coefficients[2,1]
```

3- Multiply that coefficient value by: [(the number of people for whom tobacco == 1 in that block) + (the number of people for whom
    tobacco == 0 in that block)] / (the total number of people in that
    block)

```
two_5 <- ((sum(dfc$tobacco01 == 1)) + (sum(dfc$tobacco01 == 0)))/ sum(dfc$tobacco)

three <- two*two_5
```

4- Finally, I would like to be able to add up all the values from (3) for all 100 blocks.

I know how to do each of these steps individually, but I don't know how to iterate them over 100 separate blocks. I tried using group_by(pscoreblocks) and then running a regression, but it looks like group_by() and lm() do not work well together. I have also considered using pivot_longer() to create a separate column for each block and then trying to run the regressions with the data in that format. I'd really appreciate any suggestions for how to iterate over all 100 blocks.

Data:

```
> small <- dput(dfcsmall[1:40,])
structure(list(dbrwt = c(3629, 3005, 3459, 4520, 3095.17811313023, 
3714, 3515, 3232, 3686, 4281, 2645.29691556227, 3714, 3232, 3374, 
3856, 3997, 3515, 3714, 3459, 3232, 3884, 3235, 3008.94507753983, 
3799, 2940, 3389.51332290472, 3090, 1701, 3363, 3033, 2325, 3941, 
3657, 3600, 3005, 4054, 3856, 3402, 2694.09822203382, 3413.03869100037
), tobacco01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1), pscore = c(0.00988756408875347, 0.183983728674846, 
0.24538311074894, 0.170701594663405, 0.179337494008595,         0.0770304781540708, 
0.164003166666384, 0.0773042518100593, 0.0804603038634144,     0.0611822720382283, 
0.481204657069376, 0.166016137665693, 0.107882394783232,     0.149799473798458, 
0.04130366288307, 0.0360272679038012, 0.476513676221723, 0.214910849480014, 
0.0687582392973688, 0.317662260996216, 0.206183065905609,     0.336553699970873, 
0.0559863953956171, 0.103064791185442, 0.0445362319933672,     0.17097032928289, 
0.245898950803051, 0.146235179401833, 0.284345485401689,     0.152121397241563, 
0.0395696572471225, 0.116669642645446, 0.0672219220193578,     0.297173652687617, 
0.436771917147971, 0.0517299620576624, 0.140760280612358,     0.179726730598874, 
0.0118610298424373, 0.162996197785343), pscoreblocks = structure(c(1L, 
19L, 25L, 18L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 49L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 
5L, 4L, 49L, 22L, 7L, 33L, 21L, 35L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 18L, 25L, 15L, 
29L, 16L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 31L, 45L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 2L, 17L), .Label = c("    [3.88e-05,0.0099]", 
"(0.0099,0.0198]", "(0.0198,0.0296]", "(0.0296,0.0395]", "    (0.0395,0.0493]", 
"(0.0493,0.0592]", "(0.0592,0.069]", "(0.069,0.0789]", "(0.0789,0.0888]", 
"(0.0888,0.0986]", "(0.0986,0.108]", "(0.108,0.118]", "(0.118,0.128]", 
"(0.128,0.138]", "(0.138,0.148]", "(0.148,0.158]", "(0.158,0.168]", 
"(0.168,0.177]", "(0.177,0.187]", "(0.187,0.197]", "(0.197,0.207]", 
"(0.207,0.217]", "(0.217,0.227]", "(0.227,0.237]", "(0.237,0.246]", 
"(0.246,0.256]", "(0.256,0.266]", "(0.266,0.276]", "(0.276,0.286]", 
"(0.286,0.296]", "(0.296,0.306]", "(0.306,0.315]", "(0.315,0.325]", 
"(0.325,0.335]", "(0.335,0.345]", "(0.345,0.355]", "(0.355,0.365]", 
"(0.365,0.375]", "(0.375,0.384]", "(0.384,0.394]", "(0.394,0.404]", 
"(0.404,0.414]", "(0.414,0.424]", "(0.424,0.434]", "(0.434,0.444]", 
"(0.444,0.453]", "(0.453,0.463]", "(0.463,0.473]", "(0.473,0.483]", 
"(0.483,0.493]", "(0.493,0.503]", "(0.503,0.513]", "(0.513,0.522]", 
"(0.522,0.532]", "(0.532,0.542]", "(0.542,0.552]", "(0.552,0.562]", 
"(0.562,0.572]", "(0.572,0.582]", "(0.582,0.591]", "(0.591,0.601]", 
"(0.601,0.611]", "(0.611,0.621]", "(0.621,0.631]", "(0.631,0.641]", 
"(0.641,0.651]", "(0.651,0.66]", "(0.66,0.67]", "(0.67,0.68]", 
"(0.68,0.69]", "(0.69,0.7]", "(0.7,0.71]", "(0.71,0.72]", "(0.72,0.73]", 
"(0.73,0.739]", "(0.739,0.749]", "(0.749,0.759]", "(0.759,0.769]", 
"(0.769,0.779]", "(0.779,0.789]", "(0.789,0.799]", "(0.799,0.808]", 
"(0.808,0.818]", "(0.818,0.828]", "(0.828,0.838]", "(0.838,0.848]", 
"(0.848,0.858]", "(0.858,0.868]", "(0.868,0.877]", "(0.877,0.887]", 
"(0.887,0.897]", "(0.897,0.907]", "(0.907,0.917]", "(0.917,0.927]", 
"(0.927,0.937]", "(0.937,0.946]", "(0.946,0.956]", "(0.956,0.966]", 
"(0.966,0.976]", "(0.976,0.986]"), class = "factor"), blocknumber = c(1L, 
19L, 25L, 18L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 49L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 
5L, 4L, 49L, 22L, 7L, 33L, 21L, 35L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 18L, 25L, 15L, 
29L, 16L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 31L, 45L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 2L, 17L)), row.names =     c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you include the code which you use for blocks 1 to 4 individually.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, I have now added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function to apply to each `pscoreblocks`.

```
apply_model <- function(data) {
   one <- lm(birthwt ~ tobacco01, data)
   two <- summary(one)$coefficients[2,1]
   two_5 <- ((sum(data$tobacco01 == 1)) + (sum(data$tobacco01 == 0)))/ sum(data$tobacco)
   three <- two*two_5
   return(three)
}
```

Split the data into spearate dataframe and apply this function to each chunk.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dfc %>% group_split(pscoreblocks) %>% map(apply_model)
#OR
#dfc %>% group_split(pscoreblocks) %>% map_dbl(apply_model)
```

You can also use base R :

```
lapply(split(dfc, dfc$pscoreblocks), apply_model)
```

Or with `by` :

```
by(dfc, dfc$pscoreblocks, apply_model)
```

Comment: Why would I get the following error when running this using group_split() and map() but not when I run it on its own? Error in summary(one)$coefficients[2, 1] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I think some model do not have `coefficients` or at least `[2,1]` dimension is incorrect.

Comment: When I compare the value I get for the first block when using this method, it differs from what I get when I use the same lines of code but use filter to only include the first block in the data.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add some data using which I can verify what you said.

Comment: I added some data. Please let me know if this is not in a useful format as I have not done this before. I used dput() to get this.

Comment: Someone responded here and figured out what was going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741207/splitting-data-into-chunks-and-iterating-over-each-chunk-in-r/61741994#61741994

Comment: @melbez So the function does work as expected, right? It was just a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The Question is likely to be project module.

I believe, the two main pain point in the Question is 1 & 2. Hence answering those.

**Steps:**

1. Nest your dataset using `pscoreblocks`

   `d_nested <- d %>% group_by(pscoreblocks) %>% nest()`
2. write a function to model.

   `mod_fun <- function(df){ lm( birthwt ~ tobacco01, data = df) }`
3. Use the above function to model.

   `m_d <- d_nested %>% mutate(model = map(data, mod_fun))`
4. create another function to extract coefficients of each model.

   `b_fun <- function(mod){ coefficients(mod)[[1]] }`
5. Finally, use the above function.

   `m_d %>% transmute(coeff = map_dbl(model, b_fun))`

will give you output [*coeffs are same as data because we only have one data points per group*] as

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   pscoreblocks [3]
  pscoreblocks   coeff
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 (0.177, 0.187]  3425
2 (0.158, 0.168]  3527
3 (0.335, 0.345]  1638
```

**Data:**

```
structure(list(birthwt = c(3425, 3527, 1638), tobacco01 = c(0, 
1, 1), pscore = c(0.18, 0.15, 0.34), pscoreblocks = c("(0.177, 0.187]", 
"(0.158, 0.168]", "(0.335, 0.345]")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")) -> d
```