# Splitting data into chunks and iterating over each chunk in R

Tags: r, group-by, grouping, tidyverse, lapply

I have a dataframe structured like this:

```
birthwt  tobacco01  pscore  pscoreblocks     blocknumber
3425     0          0.18    (0.177, 0.187]   1
3527     1          0.15    (0.158, 0.168]   2
1638     1          0.34    (0.335, 0.345]   3
```

**Explaining the data**: The birthwt column is a continuous variable measuring birth weight in grams. The tobacco01 column contains values of 0 or 1. The pscore column contains probability values between 0 and 1. The pscoreblocks takes the pscore column and breaks it down into 100 equally sized blocks. The block number provides a number for each block, so it goes from 1 to 100.

I am trying to do the following for each of the blocks in pscoreblocks.

```
apply_model <- function(data) {
   one <- lm(birthwt ~ tobacco01, data)
   two <- one$coefficients[[2]]
   two_5 <- ((sum(data$tobacco01 == 1)) + (sum(data$tobacco01 == 0)))/ sum(data$tobacco)
   three <- two*two_5
   return(three)
}
```

**Method 1**: One way of doing this (inefficiently) would be to use filter to create a separate dataframe for each block.

```
data1 <- data %>% filter(blocknumber == 1)
```

I could then manually run the function above on each block.

**Method 2**: However, I would like to be able to run this efficiently for 100 blocks.

The following solution has been proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649029/running-iterated-regressions-for-data-divided-into-n-chunks-in-r/61651926?noredirect=1#comment109084734_61651926):

```
data %>% group_split(blocknumber) %>% map(apply_model)
```

I get the same results here as when I use this:

```
lapply(split(data, data$blocknumber), apply_model)
```

**The Problem**:

When I compare the values I get when using Method 1 to the value using Method 2, I was expecting to get the same results. If I filter out block number 1 and run the analysis vs. looking at the value labeled (1) in the 2nd method, I do not get the same values. Why am I not getting the same value here?

More generally, how do I split the data into chunks based on a column value and then iterate to run a function that involves a term that refers to the dataframe being used?

*Reproducible example*:

```
> small <- dput(dfcsmall[1:40,])
structure(list(birthwt = c(3629, 3005, 3459, 4520, 3095.17811313023, 
3714, 3515, 3232, 3686, 4281, 2645.29691556227, 3714, 3232, 3374, 
3856, 3997, 3515, 3714, 3459, 3232, 3884, 3235, 3008.94507753983, 
3799, 2940, 3389.51332290472, 3090, 1701, 3363, 3033, 2325, 3941, 
3657, 3600, 3005, 4054, 3856, 3402, 2694.09822203382, 3413.03869100037
), tobacco01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1), pscore = c(0.00988756408875347, 0.183983728674846, 
0.24538311074894, 0.170701594663405, 0.179337494008595,         0.0770304781540708, 
0.164003166666384, 0.0773042518100593, 0.0804603038634144,     0.0611822720382283, 
0.481204657069376, 0.166016137665693, 0.107882394783232,     0.149799473798458, 
0.04130366288307, 0.0360272679038012, 0.476513676221723, 0.214910849480014, 
0.0687582392973688, 0.317662260996216, 0.206183065905609,     0.336553699970873, 
0.0559863953956171, 0.103064791185442, 0.0445362319933672,     0.17097032928289, 
0.245898950803051, 0.146235179401833, 0.284345485401689,     0.152121397241563, 
0.0395696572471225, 0.116669642645446, 0.0672219220193578,     0.297173652687617, 
0.436771917147971, 0.0517299620576624, 0.140760280612358,     0.179726730598874, 
0.0118610298424373, 0.162996197785343), pscoreblocks = structure(c(1L, 
19L, 25L, 18L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 49L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 
5L, 4L, 49L, 22L, 7L, 33L, 21L, 35L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 18L, 25L, 15L, 
29L, 16L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 31L, 45L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 2L, 17L), .Label = c("    [3.88e-05,0.0099]", 
"(0.0099,0.0198]", "(0.0198,0.0296]", "(0.0296,0.0395]", "    (0.0395,0.0493]", 
"(0.0493,0.0592]", "(0.0592,0.069]", "(0.069,0.0789]", "(0.0789,0.0888]", 
"(0.0888,0.0986]", "(0.0986,0.108]", "(0.108,0.118]", "(0.118,0.128]", 
"(0.128,0.138]", "(0.138,0.148]", "(0.148,0.158]", "(0.158,0.168]", 
"(0.168,0.177]", "(0.177,0.187]", "(0.187,0.197]", "(0.197,0.207]", 
"(0.207,0.217]", "(0.217,0.227]", "(0.227,0.237]", "(0.237,0.246]", 
"(0.246,0.256]", "(0.256,0.266]", "(0.266,0.276]", "(0.276,0.286]", 
"(0.286,0.296]", "(0.296,0.306]", "(0.306,0.315]", "(0.315,0.325]", 
"(0.325,0.335]", "(0.335,0.345]", "(0.345,0.355]", "(0.355,0.365]", 
"(0.365,0.375]", "(0.375,0.384]", "(0.384,0.394]", "(0.394,0.404]", 
"(0.404,0.414]", "(0.414,0.424]", "(0.424,0.434]", "(0.434,0.444]", 
"(0.444,0.453]", "(0.453,0.463]", "(0.463,0.473]", "(0.473,0.483]", 
"(0.483,0.493]", "(0.493,0.503]", "(0.503,0.513]", "(0.513,0.522]", 
"(0.522,0.532]", "(0.532,0.542]", "(0.542,0.552]", "(0.552,0.562]", 
"(0.562,0.572]", "(0.572,0.582]", "(0.582,0.591]", "(0.591,0.601]", 
"(0.601,0.611]", "(0.611,0.621]", "(0.621,0.631]", "(0.631,0.641]", 
"(0.641,0.651]", "(0.651,0.66]", "(0.66,0.67]", "(0.67,0.68]", 
"(0.68,0.69]", "(0.69,0.7]", "(0.7,0.71]", "(0.71,0.72]", "(0.72,0.73]", 
"(0.73,0.739]", "(0.739,0.749]", "(0.749,0.759]", "(0.759,0.769]", 
"(0.769,0.779]", "(0.779,0.789]", "(0.789,0.799]", "(0.799,0.808]", 
"(0.808,0.818]", "(0.818,0.828]", "(0.828,0.838]", "(0.838,0.848]", 
"(0.848,0.858]", "(0.858,0.868]", "(0.868,0.877]", "(0.877,0.887]", 
"(0.887,0.897]", "(0.897,0.907]", "(0.907,0.917]", "(0.917,0.927]", 
"(0.927,0.937]", "(0.937,0.946]", "(0.946,0.956]", "(0.956,0.966]", 
"(0.966,0.976]", "(0.976,0.986]"), class = "factor"), blocknumber = c(1L, 
19L, 25L, 18L, 19L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 49L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 
5L, 4L, 49L, 22L, 7L, 33L, 21L, 35L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 18L, 25L, 15L, 
29L, 16L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 31L, 45L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 2L, 17L)), row.names =     c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Both methods return `NA` for me

Comment: @DiceboyT I have tried to add one. Please let me know if you need it in a different format than what I have included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are giving equivalent results, but I believe you're indexing based on *position* instead of *name*:

```
data %>% filter(blocknumber == 6) %>% apply_model()
# [1] -2090
```

If we then try to index `model_list` with position 6, it's not equal:

```
data_split <- data %>% group_split(blocknumber)
models <- data_split %>% map(apply_model)
models[[6]]
# [1] NA
```

But that's because `data_split[[6]]` isn't the same as `data %>% filter(blocknumber == 6)`:

```
data_split[[6]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   birthwt tobacco01 pscore pscoreblocks   blocknumber
#     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>                <int>
# 1    4281         0 0.0612 (0.0592,0.069]           7
# 2    3459         0 0.0688 (0.0592,0.069]           7
# 3    3657         0 0.0672 (0.0592,0.069]           7
```

You can fix this by assigning names and then indexing by name:

```
names(models) <- data_split %>% map("blocknumber") %>% map_chr(unique)
models[["6"]]
# [1] -2090
```

`base::split` also preserves names by default so I generally prefer to use it:

```
models <- data %>% split(.$blocknumber) %>% map(apply_model) 
models[["6"]]
# [1] -2090
```